# Powershell Lync/AD syntax

Tags: powershell, lync, lync-2013

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out why the synatx below is wrong.  I'm fairly new to powershell, so any help would be appreciated.

The issue seems to be with the `$false` in the filter variable, without that it works.

```
$BU = 'corp','sales'
$filter="(extensionattribute6 -like '*514' -or extensionattribute6 -like '*66048') -and msRTCSIP-UserEnabled -eq $false"

$BU | % {get-aduser -Properties displayname -Filter  $filter  -SearchBase 'ou=users,ou=$_,ou=Business Units,dc=biz,dc=com' -SearchScope Subtree}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around the content for `$filter`

```
$filter='(extensionattribute6 -like "*514" -or extensionattribute6 -like "*66048") -and msRTCSIP-UserEnabled -eq $false'
```

Double quotes will replace variables with their value, so it searches for `msRTCSIP-UserEnabled -eq False` (which throws a syntax error) instead of `msRTCSIP-UserEnabled -eq $false`.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer (or any other one) solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.